# Error when running shell command in C++ ubuntu linux

Tags: c++, linux, shell, loops, ubuntu

```
//all variables are declared in a struct StockPile
//...
string itemid;    
string itemdesc;  
string datepurchased;
string line;
int unitprice;
int totalsales;
std::string myline;
//...

void displaydailyreport() {

    ifstream myfile("stockdatabase.txt");   

    for(int i=0;std::getline(myfile,myline);i++) 
    {
        // Trying to grep all data with a specific date from a textfile,
        cout<<system("grep "<<stockpile[i].datepurchased<<" stockdatabase.txt")<<endl;
    }   
    cout<<endl; 
}
```

When I try to compile it gives me this error :

```
note:template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Main.cpp:853:40: note:   mismatched types ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>’ and ‘const char [6]’
     cout<<system("grep "<<stockpile[i].datepurchased<<" stockdatabase.txt")<<endl;
```

When I try to run with this it works fine :

```
 cout<<system("grep '9oct16' stockdatabase.txt")
```

`stockpile[i].datepurchased` is where I can `cout` the different dates stored in my textfile , I can print out `stockpile[i].datepurchased` values in the for loop.
    It returns string 9oct16 , 10oct16 etc. but when I try to use shell command it wont compile .

Comment: In `"grep "<<stockpile[i].datepurchased`, the compiler couldn't figure out what you meant by `<<`. Neither could I.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<<` operator is a stream operator. While you can concatenate strings (and c-strings) with them on a stream (like `cout`) it does not work that way without actually working on a stream.

Lets just take the statement inside your system call separately

```
"grep "<<stockpile[i].datepurchased<<" stockdatabase.txt"
```

The `<<` is not meant to be used that way without a stream object to "stream" into.

What you can do though is the following:

```
std::string command = "grep "
                      + stockpile[i].datepurchased
                      + " stockdatabase.txt"
system(command.c_str());
```

This does several things.

- create a `std::string` to store the system command
- because `datepurchased` is a `std::string` already you can use the + operator on the other c-strings to concatenate them.
- system is expecting a `const char*` as argument. So to be able to pass the c-string to the function we use the `c_str()` function of the `std::string`

You can also shorten the statement to this:

```
system( ("grep "+stockpile[i].datepurchased+" stockdatabase.txt").c_str());
```

Because a temporary `std::string` will be created by the + operator you can access its `c_str()` function directly.

Answer (score 0):

`<<` is an operator to append to a stream, it does not do string concatenation. So please use `+` instead of `<<` to generate the grep command.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%3C%3C/

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
cout<<system("grep "<<stockpile[i].datepurchased<<" stockdatabase.txt")<<endl
```

Your need a stringstream object to stream the parts of the command first.
Or build the command using string like that:

```
std::string command = "grep ";
command +=stockpile[i].datepurchased;
command +=" stockdatabase.txt";

cout<<system( command.c_str() )<<endl
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your compiler quite clearly tells you what's wrong: You are trying to use the stream operator `<<` with two non-matching types, namely `const char [6]` (aka `"grep "`) and a `std::ostream` (aka `stockpile[i].datepurchased`). You simply cannot stream into char arrays or strings. That's what streams are designed for in STL. So one possible solution could be:

```
std::cout << system((std::string("grep ") + stockpile[i].datepurchased + std::string(" stockdatabase.txt")).c_str()) << std::endl;
```

Didn't test it, though ;)